# Simple and fast way to install sass in container ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby, docker, sass, containers, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run a script that compiles my sass in a "build" container.
Since this container will repeatedly be restarted I need a robust and quick way to install or use sass. (including ruby and dependencies)

Is there a simple way for sass to be available in a container for scss compiling?

There is a solution using a ruby container but this is not possible in my case since i already need a specific container image for the build itself.
Using another container and named volumes is also not possible in my case.

Comment: Can you use npm? If so, you can use node-sass. Let me know if this sounds like a solution for you and I can write up a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Docker image that inherits the specific Ruby image you need, add your changes to it, and use it instead.

For example, if you currently use `debian:jessie`, then you can create a new `Dockerfile` with:

```
FROM debian:jessie
# Now you install all the dependencies including Ruby... etc
RUN gem install sass
```

Then you can build and image from that file, and publish that image to a docker registry, and use it instead of the one you are currently using.

Take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/1d0fe6a9d5c75d8a114fb03016f528d68c613d80/2.4/jessie/slim/Dockerfile) of some Ruby docker image to see how you can install Ruby and dependencies. Ofcourse, you are free to install it however you want (natively, using rbenv or using rvm... etc).